# How to keep the same value of a field for multiple calls to a Class

Tags: java, class, methods, encapsulation

I'm running into a problem that I can't solve basically, I'm trying to build a code for a house and I wanna make multiple calls to the house without having to turn on the light every single time

My field value

```
private boolean turnon = false;
```

and then my method to turn on the the lights

```
public void turnon() {
   
    turnon = true;
}
```

Basically what I want to avoid is to not call the method every single time I wanna add a new House, basically once I turn it on it turns on for every instance of the class.

```
House x = new House();
x.turnon();
```

So let's say I create another class of House

```
House y = new House();
```

I want the lights to be turned on in y since I've already turned them on in x

I tried defining the method statically but it didn't work, any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your House class, add this:

```
public House() {
    turnon();
}
```

I figured out the OP wants to have the first one's lights not turn on, so you can make a constructor with an argument of `boolean` called "lightsOn" and if true, it will turn on the lights, and if false, will not.

```
public house(boolean lightsOn) {
    if (lightsOn) {
        turnon();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply add another constructor with an argument and only call that constructor on the first instance of "House"

```
public House() {
    turnon();
}

// Only for the first house
public House(boolean lightsOff) {
    turnon = false;
}
```

Comment: If this helps, please accept this as the answer. there should be a gray checkmark next to any question. Please click it

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are creating a new house, you can initialize the value of field turnOn(notice the camelcase convention ) in the constructor.

```
    public House(boolean turnOn) {
// initializing other fields 
        this.turnOn = turnOn; 
    }
```

Then you can provide regular getter and setter to access the turnOn field.
When creating other houses , you can simply use your no-arg constructor.

```
    public House() {
// initializing other fields 
       
    }
```

Comment: But this wouldnt work for the first iteration since, the light is off this would just turn it on even at the first iteration since you need to turn it on the first time

Comment: Whenver you create a new house, you want the turnOn field to be true, right ? 
I didn't follow your comment, please elaborate

Comment: Basically whenever I create a new house after the initial house I want turnOn field to be true, for the first one I dont want it to be true unless I call turnOn

Comment: for the initial house, you can call a parameterized constructor and for  other houses, you can call a no-arg constructor.

Comment: But both of them have parameters by House class has a parameter of area.

Comment: suppose, if house y ( in your example ) decides to set the turnOn field to be false, will that affect house x  ( changing the value of field turnOn to false for house x ) ?

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental reason for the confusion here is:
'House' and a light 'Switch' don't belong to the same class!

So I think you should model House and a Switch as different classes.
And just make the house object 'aggregate' a set of 'Switches' and other objects in the house.

Eg:

```
class House {
  List<ElectricalFitting> devices;
}

class Switch extends ElectricalFitting {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract a default state for the light as static field into a base class.
Your House class extends this base class, inhertites the default state field and copies in it's constructer the default to the instance state.  The two setters change both, the default and instance state.

If for example the default state is light off (false), every new instance of House has it's light turned off.

But if you turn the light on (true) in one house than the default change to true and every new instance has the light turned on.

Every existing instance of House acts independenly to all other houses on turning light on or off.

```
public abstract class HouseBase {
    
    protectet static boolean defaultSwitchState = false;
    
}


public class House extends HouseBase {
    
    private boolean turnOn = false;
    
    
    public House() {
        turnOn = defaultSwitchState;
    }
    
    
    public void turnOn() {
        super.defaultSwitchState = true;
        turnOn = true;
    }

    public void turnOff() {
        super.defaultSwitchState = false;
        turnOn = false;
    }

}
```